# pass json from ajax to php

Tags: php, json, ajax

JS file:

```
var jsonsave = [];

var dado = new Object();
dado.name = "bob";
dado.age = "000";
dado.test = "test";
var jason = JSON.stringify(dado);
jsonsave.push(jason);


$.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               dataType: "JSON",
               url: "http://localhost/moodle/my/index.php",
               data: "data="+jsonsave+"&file=true",
               success: function(data){
                   console.log('work');
               },
               error: function(data)
               {
                    console.log(data);

               }
           });
```

Arquivo php:

```
$arquivo = $_POST['data'];
$value= json_decode($arquivo, TRUE);
```

I call a php page from ajax, but i can't take the json's value, it came null,do you have some idea?

Comment: Why are you adding jason to jasonsave? You are concatenating a string with an array. Put jason in there directly: `data: "data="+jason+"&file=true",`

Comment: it's because i will add more array into this variable , so i just send when i pass to this "function"

Comment: But you still can't concatenate an array with a string. You need to use JSON,stringify on jsonsave. Btw. you can also provide an object to `data` and jQuery is doing the JSON encoding then.

Comment: so, how i put the array into data?
i use json.stringify there

Comment: Check out the first example: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#entry-examples

Comment: Does the browser console shows any error?

Answer (score -1):

In your AJAX call you specified 
dataType: "JSON"
which means that your call expects JSON as returned value from server.

On the other hand, on the PHP side you are decoding POST, which is converting JSON to PHP object (structure), and also you are not returning anything.

Solution is simple: send JSON structure back (try with json_encode, maybe in addition with appropriate headers), and that should do to trick.

Comment: you said for put like this ?
  jsonsave = json_encode(jsonsave); 
i did this but show this on console: json_encode is not defined

Comment: You can't use json_encode in JS. It is PHP function. Within your code you are sending to server data like this:
data: {"name":"bob","age":"000","test":"test"}
file: true

I am not sure from your example what is your final goal on the server side, but If you want to send back json to test you AJAX call, just do this:
$arquivo = $_POST['data'];
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $arquivo;